# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while using online in create index

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql

in below procedure when I am using online then during execution this is giving error "ORA-01031: insufficient privilege" while running without online it is running fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p_temp_1 is
begin
execute immediate 'CREATE INDEX pp_temp1  ON p_temp  (access_no) online ';
end;
```

which privileges i need to give ?

Comment: could you please share exactly what privileges i need to give to my super user and it will be great help if you can share statement too

Comment: We do not want to use AUTHID CURRENT_USER , we want to give missing privileges

Comment: What do you see if you run the create statement outside a procedure?

Comment: index is getting created when running outside the procedure

Comment: So just to clarify: outside the procedure you can create the index with or without the `online`option as plain SQL statements; when you execute the procedure it creates the index if the statement does not have `online` but you get the error if it does have `online`? It might be useful to edit the question to show all four scenarios and the results you get; and also show which version and patch level of Oracle you are using.

Answer (score 2):

> Checked for the privilege and the user was granted “CREATE TABLE” but
>   from within RESOURCE role.Stored PL/SQL requires a direct grant and
>   therefore the procedure fails with ‘insufficient privileges’. So
>   granted ‘CREATE TABLE’ system privilege directly to the user, after
>   which the index got created.

[From here](https://aprakash.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/create-index-online-fails-with-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges/)

Comment: It might be, `create index online` requires `create table` permissions(works fine), but if you executes it in pl/sql it need ti be granted directly. Exactly this case.

Comment: that articles, I've quoted state that if you use `online` option, it put some lock and create some kind of system journal table (that's where you need create table privileges as I understood).. might be wrong

Comment: OK, sorry, I hadn't read that properly I guess, and I still can't recreate it in 11g or 12c while playing with privs. Maybe a PSU fixed it...